# How to set a value in a field according the item selected in the picker?

Tags: react-native, picker

first I Wanna say I'm beginner in react-native, I'm having a situation where I get a list that contains some cars, I'm using Picker to list all those cars. When I select a car, in the field below I need to be shown the Km of this car, how do I do it?

[Image with Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GqFqO.png)

[List of the cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfklE.png)

[Car selected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkzDA.png)

[Screenshot of Debuger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXD7s.png)

Here my code where I get the list of cars and make the selection:

```js
<Content>
    <Form>
        <Picker
            placeholder='Select the car'
            placeholderStyle={{ color: '#000' }}
            selectedValue={this.state.descViatura}
            onValueChange={this.onValueChange.bind(this)}
        >
            {
                list_viaturas.map((item, key) => {
                    return <Picker.Item
                        label={[item.marca, ' ', item.modelo, ' ', item.matricula]}
                        value={item.id}
                        key={item}
                    />
                })
            }
        </Picker>
    </Form>
</Content>
```

My componentDidMount():

```js
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`${API_MOTORISTAS_VIATURAS}`, {
        'param1': this.state.api_token
    }, {
            "headers": {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            }
        }).then((dataSource) => {
            this.setState({
                viaturas: true,
                dataSource: dataSource.data['data'],
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
}
```

My onValueChange():

```js
onValueChange(value: string) {
    this.setState({
        descViatura: value,
    });
}
```

The field where I need show the km:

```js
<TextInput
    style={styles.input}
    value={this.state.km_actuais}
    keyboardType={'numeric'}
    placeholderTextColor={'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)'}
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
/>
```

The JSON I get from my API:

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "matricula": "55-RR-80",
            "modelo": "C3",
            "foto": "230530201805185aff5c3af0ac0.jpeg",
            "lotacao": 4,
            "km_actuais": "85555",
            "marca_id": 203,
            "grupo_id": 5,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2018-05-18 22:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2018-05-18 21:01:51",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-02 16:16:25",
            "marca": "Citroen"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "matricula": "95-ER-75",
            "modelo": "Vito",
            "foto": "230620201805185aff5c6cb8f12.png",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": "36500",
            "marca_id": 237,
            "grupo_id": 7,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2018-05-18 23:06:20",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2018-05-18 21:03:53",
            "updated_at": "2018-07-19 01:35:37",
            "marca": "Mercedes"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "matricula": "30-KJ-98",
            "modelo": "Starbus",
            "foto": "230609201805185aff5c611d183.png",
            "lotacao": 16,
            "km_actuais": "65900",
            "marca_id": 237,
            "grupo_id": 8,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2018-05-24 21:35:35",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2018-05-18 21:05:10",
            "updated_at": "2018-06-26 20:55:25",
            "marca": "Mercedes"
        },
        {
            "id": 261,
            "matricula": "61-13-FR",
            "modelo": "Defender",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": "500",
            "marca_id": 3124,
            "grupo_id": 136,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "1995-09-11 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-08 09:59:21",
            "updated_at": "2019-02-08 11:01:28",
            "marca": "Land Rover Defender"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "matricula": "80-HH-65",
            "modelo": "S",
            "foto": "230546201805185aff5c4a8b517.png",
            "lotacao": 4,
            "km_actuais": "25001",
            "marca_id": 237,
            "grupo_id": 6,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2018-05-18 23:05:46",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2018-05-18 21:02:58",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-23 14:32:05",
            "marca": "Mercedes"
        },
        {
            "id": 269,
            "matricula": "27-30-GV",
            "modelo": "Defender",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 3124,
            "grupo_id": 136,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:02:39",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:02:39",
            "marca": "Land Rover Defender"
        },
        {
            "id": 270,
            "matricula": "QF-22-82",
            "modelo": "Defender",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 3124,
            "grupo_id": 136,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:03:30",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:03:30",
            "marca": "Land Rover Defender"
        },
        {
            "id": 271,
            "matricula": "12-50-AI",
            "modelo": "DEFENDER",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 3124,
            "grupo_id": 136,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:04:03",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:04:03",
            "marca": "Land Rover Defender"
        },
        {
            "id": 272,
            "matricula": "96-73-AH",
            "modelo": "DEFENDER",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 3124,
            "grupo_id": 136,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:04:40",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:04:40",
            "marca": "Land Rover Defender"
        },
        {
            "id": 273,
            "matricula": "06-29-HU",
            "modelo": "DEFENDER",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 3124,
            "grupo_id": 136,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:05:13",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:05:13",
            "marca": "Land Rover Defender"
        },
        {
            "id": 274,
            "matricula": "45-DC-07",
            "modelo": "TRANSIT",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 216,
            "grupo_id": 8,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:06:06",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:06:06",
            "marca": "Ford"
        },
        {
            "id": 275,
            "matricula": "85-OR-89",
            "modelo": "TRANSIT CUSTOM",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 216,
            "grupo_id": 8,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:06:47",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:06:47",
            "marca": "Ford"
        },
        {
            "id": 276,
            "matricula": "79-38-QR",
            "modelo": "DEFENDER",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 8,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 227,
            "grupo_id": 136,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 10:07:24",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 10:07:24",
            "marca": "Land Rover"
        },
        {
            "id": 277,
            "matricula": "89-SI-78",
            "modelo": "POLARIS RZR",
            "foto": "grey.jpg",
            "lotacao": 2,
            "km_actuais": null,
            "marca_id": 205,
            "grupo_id": 5,
            "orga_id": 3,
            "data_matricula": "2019-01-16 00:00:00",
            "transfer_zona": 1,
            "transfer_km": 2,
            "tours": 0,
            "shuttle": 0,
            "chauffer": 0,
            "created_at": "2019-01-16 12:12:54",
            "updated_at": "2019-01-16 12:12:54",
            "marca": "DAF"
        }
    ],
    "error": "200"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the index of the item as your value in your Picker item, and in `onValueChange` method, and then set your `km_actuais` state variable to the value based on the index in your original data, like below:

```
...

list_viaturas.map((item, key) => {
    return <Picker.Item
            label={[item.marca, ' ', item.modelo, ' ', item.matricula]}
            value={key}
            key={key}
           />
})

...


onValueChange(value: string) {
    let kms = this.state.dataSource[value].km_actuais;

    this.setState({
        descViatura: value,
        km_actuais: kms
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello @Jono, I assume the index value you are saying should be represented by my Key, but the value that returns from my Key is undefined, If I put in the index place the word Key, it also returns as undefined. I updated my question and put another picture for you to see, the name is screenshot

Comment: Mmm not sure why it's not working. Works for me. Check this snack - https://snack.expo.io/@jonoh/picker-example

Comment: The index value should represent the index of the item you've selected (position) in the list of Picker Items

Comment: This example seems to solve just the problem I am having, I will try to apply in my code and inform you if it worked, thank you very much for the help, it has helped a lot to clear the mind

Comment: Hello Jono, I think I figured out why my picker is not picking the Picker index, just like yours is, the reason is because I'm using the native-base picker. I tried running your code using the native-base picker and they also did not show the index.
Can you tell me if there is any way to resolve this by continuing to use the native-base picker?

Comment: I ask this because in all this application I'm going to have about 20 pickers like that, and they're all already native-based.
I put my code in the snack so you can analyze in more detail, thank you already, follow the link: https://snack.expo.io/@vbernal/cars-pickers

Comment: Ah I see. In that case you can use a workaround by using your item index/key as your `value` in your picker item instead. Have updated my answer. Let me know if it works

Comment: It's my pleasure:) Glad it worked! If you could mark as accepted answer that would be great! Good luck with the rest of the project